# InkEdit control adds line breaks to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a userform for data entry and storing the contents in a cell.

When the form loads it copies the cells contents into the InkEdit box on the form, closing it copies the editied text back into the cell it came from.

For some reason when it copies back into the cell it adds line breaks where there are already line breaks. Loading up the form over and over just adds more and more line breaks!

Does anyone know why this is happening and a possible solution?

```
Private Sub CMDExit_Click()
    Sheets("Comments").Range("B1") = InkEdit1.Text
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Sheets("Comments").Range("B1").Copy
    PasteToObj InkEdit1.hWnd
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250102/discussion-on-question-by-olly-walker-inkedit-control-adds-line-breaks-to-cells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your data with this code and it removed the extra line breaks

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim i As Long

    TestString = Sheets("Comments").Range("B1").Value

    Do While InStr(1, TestString, vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
        TestString = Replace(TestString, vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    Loop
    Sheets("Comments").Range("B1").Value = TestString
End Sub
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

To incorporate it in your code, you can use it like this

```
Private Sub CMDExit_Click()
    Dim TestString As String

    TestString = InkEdit1.Text

    Do While InStr(1, TestString, vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
        TestString = Replace(TestString, vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    Loop
    
    Sheets("Comments").Range("B1").Value = TestString
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible to see your file?

Comment: I updated the above post. You may want to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: You're amazing thank you so much! Very insightful to see you work through the problem and come up with the solution too! I would upvote but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: Glad to be of help. It is just that I could not find why is it adding the line breaks in the first place. The InkEdit1 control doesn't work on my PC. Nor there is mention of this behaviour on the web... Also can you delete your other comments before the last link. I will delete mine. They are just adding to the noise :D

Comment: All done - really appreciate your help, I can now upvote too so please accept that too :)

Comment: Lol thanks. It was not for the upvotes though... Anyways, it is time for my gym. Chat later.